# Accessing my own type (data type) inside my own type (data type2) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Alright so I have two types:

```
data Ingredient = Ingredient { potato :: String, amount :: Int, cookingTime :: Int }

data Soup = Soup { availableTime :: Int, recipe :: [Ingredient], shoppingList :: [Ingredient], canBeDone :: Bool  }
```

now if I want to compare the "available Time" and the "cookingTime" of an Ingredient (basically if I have enough time to cook that ingredient if I only have "availableTime" to cook the whole soup).
And if I can cook the Ingredient in my soup, the Ingredient gets shifted into the shoppingList list.
How do I go about that?
Here's what I came up with:

```
doIHaveTime :: Soup -> Soup
doIHaveTime Soup{availableTime = a, recipe = [Ingredient{cookingTime = b}] } = if a >= b then Soup{ shoppingList = b:xs } else show "Can't be done."
```

does that way of thinking make sense?
These are the errors I get:

> soupExample.hs:6:128: error:
> • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Soup’
> Expected type: Soup
> Actual type: String
> • In the expression: show "Can't be done."
> In the expression:
> if a >= b then
> Soup {shoppingList = b : xs}
> else
> show "Can't be done."
> In an equation for ‘doIHaveTime’:
> doIHaveTime
> (Soup {availableTime = a, recipe = [Ingredient {cookingTime = b}]})
> = if a >= b then
> Soup {shoppingList = b : xs}
> else
> show "Can't be done."
> Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: `recipe = [Ingredient{cookingTime = b}]` will only handle recipes with _one_ ingredient, and crash on the other cases. You can use `recipe = is` to bind the whole list, or do two cases, `recipe = []` and `recipe = Ingredient{cookingTime = b} : is`.

Comment: Also, the type `Soup -> Soup` looks wrong, since you are not returning a soup if there's not enough time. Maybe you want `Soup -> Maybe Soup` ?

Comment: `shoppingList` should probably not be part of `Soup`; that should be a list of `Ingredient`s independent of whatever `Soup` requires the ingredients.

Comment: I should probably mention that record field access is one of Haskell's weakest points. There are some partial solutions (notably *optics*) that you'll probably want to learn about once you get some more experience.

Answer (score 1):

To handle multiple ingredients in a soup you can use `all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` to check if every ingredient in the recipe can be cooked in the available time:

```
enoughTime = all ((>=available) . cookingTime) ingredients
```

Then you have to return a `Soup` in both `if` and `else` branches. In total this can look like this:

```
doIHaveTime :: Soup -> Soup
doIHaveTime soup@Soup{ availableTime = available, recipe = ingredients }
    = if enoughTime
        -- add ingredients to shoppingList and set canBeDone to True
        then soup { shoppingList = ingredients
                  , canBeDone = True }
        -- clear shoppingList and set canBeDone to False
        else soup { shoppingList = []
                  , canBeDone = False }
  where enoughTime = all ((>=available) . cookingTime) ingredients
```

Note that I used `soup@Soup{ ... }` to pattern match and store the value at the same time in the variable `soup`. That way you only have to modify the two fields `shoppingList` and `canBeDone`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm still getting one error though. so as I understand this, in that last line "where enoughTime = all ((>=available) . cookingTime) ingredients" all takes a function, in this case >=, and it tests if cookingTime of the current ingredient out of the list of ingredients is greater or equal than the availableTime specified at the top. (Right?). So "all" takes an argument from the Soup-datatype (available), and one from the Ingredient datatype (cookingTime) and runs them along the list (ingredients). Yes?

Comment: My actual program works on process scheduling, and I'm only getting an error on that last line.
And these are the Data Types:
`
data Prozess = Prozess {  pid       :: String,
                          arrival   :: Int,
                          computing :: Int} deriving (Show)


data State = State {      new       :: [Prozess],
                          run       :: Prozess,
                          ready     :: [Prozess],
                          time      :: Int,
                          chart     :: String }`

Comment: And this is the function:

update_ready :: State -> State
update_ready state@State { time = t, new = process }
              = if isReady
                --add to ready state list
                then state {ready = process}
                --else clear list
                else state { ready = []}
              where isReady = all ((>=time) . arrival) process

Comment: Just change `>=time` to `>=t`. `time` is the member function and `t` is the local variable you assign while pattern matching.